# Scala Unpivot Table

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark-sql, pivot, unpivot

SCALA

I have a table with this struct:

| FName | SName | Email | Jan 2021 | Feb 2021 | Mar 2021 | Total 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Micheal | Scott | scarrel@gmail.com | 4000 | 5000 | 3400 | 50660 |
| Dwight | Schrute | dschrute@gmail.com | 1200 | 6900 | 1000 | 35000 |
| Kevin | Malone | kmalone@gmail.com | 9000 | 6000 | 18000 | 32000 |

And i want to transform it to:
[image]

I tried with 'stack' method but i couldn't get it to work.
Thanks

Comment: What version of spark & scala are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten the monthly/total columns via `explode` as shown below:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("Micheal", "Scott", "scarrel@gmail.com", 4000, 5000, 3400, 50660),
  ("Dwight", "Schrute", "dschrute@gmail.com", 1200, 6900, 1000, 35000),
  ("Kevin", "Malone", "kmalone@gmail.com", 9000, 6000, 18000, 32000)
).toDF("FName","SName", "Email", "Jan 2021", "Feb 2021", "Mar 2021", "Total 2021")

val moYrCols = Array("Jan 2021", "Feb 2021", "Mar 2021", "Total 2021")  // (**)
val otherCols = df.columns diff moYrCols
val structCols = moYrCols.map{ c =>
    val moYr = split(lit(c), "\\s+")
    struct(moYr(1).as("Year"), moYr(0).as("Month"), col(c).as("Value"))
  }

df.
  withColumn("flattened", explode(array(structCols: _*))).
  select(otherCols.map(col) :+ $"flattened.*": _*).
  show
/*
+-------+-------+------------------+----+-----+-----+
|  FName|  SName|             Email|Year|Month|Value|
+-------+-------+------------------+----+-----+-----+
|Micheal|  Scott| scarrel@gmail.com|2021|  Jan| 4000|
|Micheal|  Scott| scarrel@gmail.com|2021|  Feb| 5000|
|Micheal|  Scott| scarrel@gmail.com|2021|  Mar| 3400|
|Micheal|  Scott| scarrel@gmail.com|2021|Total|50660|
| Dwight|Schrute|dschrute@gmail.com|2021|  Jan| 1200|
| Dwight|Schrute|dschrute@gmail.com|2021|  Feb| 6900|
| Dwight|Schrute|dschrute@gmail.com|2021|  Mar| 1000|
| Dwight|Schrute|dschrute@gmail.com|2021|Total|35000|
|  Kevin| Malone| kmalone@gmail.com|2021|  Jan| 9000|
|  Kevin| Malone| kmalone@gmail.com|2021|  Feb| 6000|
|  Kevin| Malone| kmalone@gmail.com|2021|  Mar|18000|
|  Kevin| Malone| kmalone@gmail.com|2021|Total|32000|
+-------+-------+------------------+----+-----+-----+
*/
```

(**) Use pattern matching in case there are many columns; for example:

```
val moYrCols = df.columns.filter(_.matches("[A-Za-z]+\\s+\\d{4}"))
```

Comment: really elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
val data = Seq( 
     ("Micheal","Scott","scarrel@gmail.com",4000,5000,3400,50660),
     ("Dwight","Schrute","dschrute@gmail.com",1200,6900,1000,35000),
     ("Kevin","Malone","kmalone@gmail.com",9000,6000,18000,32000)) )
val columns = Seq("FName","SName","Email","Jan 2021","Feb 2021","Mar 2021","Total 2021")
val newColumns = Array( "FName", "SName", "Email","Total 2021" )

val df = spark.createDataFrame( data ).toDF(columns:_*)
df
 .select( 
  struct( 
   (for {column <- df.columns } yield col(column)).toSeq :_* 
  ).as("mystruct")) // create your data set with a column as a struct.
 .select( 
  $"mystruct.Fname", // refer to sub element of struct with '.' operator
  $"mystruct.sname",
  $"mystruct.Email",
  explode( /make rows for every entry in the array.
   array( 
    (for {column <- df.columns if !(newColumns contains column) } //filter out the columns we already selected
     yield // for each element yield the following expression (similar to map)
      struct(
       col(s"mystruct.$column").as("value"), // create the value column
       lit(column).as("date_year")) // create a date column
   ).toSeq :_* ) // shorthand to pass scala array into varargs for array function 
  ) 
 )
.select( 
 col("*"), // just being lazy instead of typing.
 col("col.*") // create columns from new column.  Seperating the year/date should be easy from here.
).drop($"col")
.show(false)
+--------------+--------------+------------------+-----+---------+
|mystruct.Fname|mystruct.sname|mystruct.Email    |value|date_year|
+--------------+--------------+------------------+-----+---------+
|Micheal       |Scott         |scarrel@gmail.com |4000 |Jan 2021 |
|Micheal       |Scott         |scarrel@gmail.com |5000 |Feb 2021 |
|Micheal       |Scott         |scarrel@gmail.com |3400 |Mar 2021 |
|Dwight        |Schrute       |dschrute@gmail.com|1200 |Jan 2021 |
|Dwight        |Schrute       |dschrute@gmail.com|6900 |Feb 2021 |
|Dwight        |Schrute       |dschrute@gmail.com|1000 |Mar 2021 |
|Kevin         |Malone        |kmalone@gmail.com |9000 |Jan 2021 |
|Kevin         |Malone        |kmalone@gmail.com |6000 |Feb 2021 |
|Kevin         |Malone        |kmalone@gmail.com |18000|Mar 2021 |
+--------------+--------------+------------------+-----+---------
```